# recaptcher with selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, recaptcha, captcha

I try to use selenium-java to login in a website protected with recaptcher.

To make it clear: I don't want to automate this step.

I have try to pause Selenium and manual solve the captcher, but i think recaptcher detect Selenium or chromedriver / geckodriver.

My other idear was to solve the captcher in a separat Webbrowser and pipe the token back, like JDownloader. 
But unitl now it don't work.

Does anyone have any tips on what to look for, or has other solutions?

Comment: 1. recaptcha mechanism (at least google's) detect that browser is controled by 3th party sw = doesn't let you through, it will repeat showing images again and again. 2. the token can not be used across browsers. There is (usualy) an indentifier biuld in the token. More than that, the token can valid for a few seconds only.

Comment: To be able to use webdriver at captcha-protected website you need some 'backdoor' in the recaptcha mechanism or disable the mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
You can start chrome with the parameter:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\AutomationProfile"
```

Then you can manualy solve the recaptcha.

With this code you can connect:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```